# How to display certain info of logged in user in phtml file?

Tags: magento2.3

How do I display any of the `customer_entity` table info anywhere, say some random phtml file? For example I added a field to `customer_entity` now I want to display it on `product.phtml` or something, how do I access `customer_entity` table and get that field?

Comment: what details you want to show?

Comment: table -> customer_entity
field -> secret_info

Comment: Please check updated an answer if still not let me know.

Comment: @TselmegGanhuyg why you have add a new field  to `secret_info`  and what is purpose of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this, and I added some fields more fields you should specify.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('customer_entity');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo 'customer';
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId().'<br/>';
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName().'<br/>';
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail().'<br/>';
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId().'<br/>';
    echo $secretinfo = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getSecretInfo().'<br/>';

//or

    $customer_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName ." where entity_id ='".$customer_id."' ";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);  
    //print_r($result);
    echo $secret_info = $result[0]['secret_info'];


}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: so if I added secret_info field then I should call it by $customerSession->getCustomer()->getSecret_info() ?

Comment: No for that I will let yuo know.

Comment: let me know table name please

Comment: customer_entity

Comment: ok wait I will add that in code as well

Comment: please let me know field name which is connected to customer or you want all fields need to show?

Comment: theres a field named secret_info in customer_entity

Comment: okay U can try this $customerSession->getCustomer()->getSecret_info() first. if not works I will update you

Comment: have you tried that  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getSecret_info()

Comment: if not I updated answer please check it.

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: $customerSession->getCustomer()->getSecret_info() is not working but getting it through sql seems to be working tnx man

Comment: Ok please accept answer and vote. thanks

Comment: @TselmegGanhuyg getSecret_info() will not work. you have to remove _. like, for entity_id we write getEntityId, you have to write getSecretInfo(). try this. if it work, dont need to write sql.

Comment: @Dimple Panchal hey you are right removing _ and writing getSecretInfo() works tnx man

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with your own php block class and display it using layout xml on any page.

You can define function in your block class like create file `Vendor/Module/Block/Module`

```
    protected $customer;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
  ){
       $this->customer = $customer;
  }

  public function yourMethodName(){
    $customer = $this->customer;
    $customerName =  $customer->getName(); 
    $customerId = $customer->getId(); 
    //You will get all basic detail with this $customer object
  }
```

and now you can display it on product page like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block after="product.info.details" class="Vendor/Module/Block/Module" name="customerinfo" template="Vendor_Module::customerinfo.phtml" />        
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how do I call my custom field? $customerSecretInfo= $customer->getSecret_info() ?

Comment: try this $customer->getSecretInfo()

Comment: You can check with `$customer->getData()` to check your custom attribute is fetching or not